# How to share screen capture via Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, mac

In Dropbox preferences under Import, there is an option to

> Share screenshots using Dropbox

I'm using Skitch and nothing happens when I do a screenshot.  Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: Since this is not a question about the web interface, but rather screen shots and the Mac client, this question is better off at [su].

Answer (score 0):

I am on a PC, and have no issues using Dropbox (with screenshot import) and Skitch.
When you take a screenshot, it is automatically saved in your clipboard.  Skitch has the option to select "clipboard" on the dropdown menu in the middle of Skitch's program window.